# Find which fragment has focus?

Tags: android, android-fragments, focus

I have an application which shows two fragments side by side in landscape mode. Both are always visible to the user and are dynamically loaded into a frame layout. 
 Now on orientation change to Portrait i want to show a single fragment in a single frame layout. i need to understand on which one of the fragments the user was working on during the orientation change. I am unable to understand where the user was working on. Both of the fragments have multiple EditText views. 
 I have read about

```
getWindow().getCurrentFocus();
```

in an answer, but this shall return me a view. Now if the view is deeply nested in the fragment layout, is there a better and faster way to find which of the fragments was in focus during the orientation change?

I am using the land/layout.xml and layout.xml for the layout of different orientations. The land one has 2 frame layouts and portrait only one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea:

I would track which EditText has focus.

1) Set a tag (`setTag()`) for each EditText with which panel they represent, some will be `panel1` and some will be `panel2`.

2) Set this listener on every EditText:

```
boolean firstPanelVisible = true;

editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(hasFocus){
            if(v.getTag().equals("panel1")) {
               firstPanelVisible = true;
            } else {
               firstPanelVisible = false; // the second panel is visible.
            }
        }
    }
   }
});

// TODO When changing orientation check which panel is focused.
```

Comment: Ya that shall solve it. Thanks. Il accept this but is there another way without many listners being set?

Comment: Maybe there is, your way sounds cool too. I don't see a problem with either.